# Study design when exposure more likely to lead to test for outcome

Tags: regression, survival, bias, hazard, proportional-hazards

I am doing an observational study looking at the association between a baseline exposure (binary) and the first instance of an abnormal blood test result (binary) among people with serial blood tests.

So far I have used Cox regression. However, the problem is that the baseline exposure is associated with the number of blood test results. What survival analysis method can be used to account for this?